# MySQL Database - storing data in one table or using lookups

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

I'm in the middle of redesigning an app that has 100,000s of records in a particular table (currently 250K and growing).

The table contains information of websites and domains.

For the sake of speed and resources, should I include all the data needed about either entity in the original table, or should I be using two lookup tables to store information not shared - for example one lookup table which stores all domain specific info and one which stores all site specific info?

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, a domain and site are not linked - they are two separate entities. Whilst a site does technically have a 'domain', for the purposes of what I'm doing here its classed as a site if it has traffic and revenue and some kind of visual presence other than a holding page. A domain is just the domain and nothing else. It may easier to use the examples of storing info on cars and vans, which are both vehicles but have slightly different attributes for which I would need to store information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should split them into 2 different tables because a single domain would correspond to multiple sites and if we go with the design in which the metadata of both the domain and site is stored in a single table, in that case there would need to be redundant info stored for the domain in every record of the site metadata. Instead, if we have 2 separate tables in which the domain table has one record per domain and a list of sites as one of the fields in the record and a domain name column in the site table to figure out the domain given a site, it would ensure organized storage and no redundancy of data. This is the major principle of traditional RDBMS systems and that is why we have the concept of multiple tables.

Also, you may consider using a NOSQL data store if you want to really scale your database as you said that the data is continuously increasing. [Apache HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/) may be a good solution which has this concept of grouping related information together.

**Edit:**

*Clarification in the question:*

```
Just to be clear, domain and sites are not linked. They're just different entities like a domain with no traffic or revenue would be classed as a domain and have domain related data stored for it like number of hyphens or registrar while a domain with a Wordpress install for example and exisitng traffic would be classed as a site - not a domain - and have site specific information stored. Would this change your answer?
```

In the case where they are not inter-related, I don't think that splitting the data into multiple tables is going to help in any way unless you are going for a distributed RDBMS system. In case of a single-node hosted DB, the rows are anyways indexed by the site/domain id and a large number of rows in a single table is not going to degrade performance but if you are looking at the humongous size of data and wish to divide it over multiple nodes in a cluster then having independent tables for them will help so that each table gets hosted on individual nodes and the DB is able to scale horizontally. That is the only benefit I see in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Just to be clear, domain and sites are not linked. They're just different entities like a domain with no traffic or revenue would be classed as a domain and have domain related data stored for it like number of hyphens or registrar while a domain with a Wordpress install for example and exisitng traffic would be classed as a site - not a domain - and have site specific information stored. Would this change your answer?

Comment: @thatguy -  Oh! In that case, I misinterpreted your question. I am editing the answer as per your clarification and it is under the heading Edit.

Answer (score 0):

The perfomance of your application largely depends on the type of queries the application uses. To store all data in one table does not necessarily reduce the performance but very well might enhance it. You are wasting disk space of course if your table holds the information that example.com is owned by Mr XY a few thousand times.

Normalizing your database (splitting your data up) can be helpful but one would have to know what you want to do with the data to answer that.